# What is exact difference between pipe and map in angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have searched a lot about this but i am unable to find difference between `pipe` and `map` in angular 7? Is it  necessary to use pipe in Service.ts file in angular 7?

Thanks

Comment: No, You can continue without using pipe. Map is just to typecaste your http observable into your desired output

Comment: I think you mean **RxJS** not **Angular**

Comment: Thanks for reply but i need to know about what is better to use. What is the major difference in between http `observables` using pipe and without using pipe i.e. map?

Answer (score 12):

With rxjs 5.5 and above, if you want to use any operator on an observable you just pipe them. So here `map` is just one of those operators within the `pipe`.

ex **Newer Versions 5.5**+:

```
const example = source.pipe(map(val => val + 10), first());
```

For earlier versions of `rxjs` there was no `pipe` keyword, Multiple operators were combined using `.` notation

ex **Older Versions**:

```
const example = source.map(val => val + 10).first();
```

Answer (score 7):

map(), filter(), concat(), and flatMap() these are the operators offered by the RxJS library.
You can use pipes to link these operators together. Pipes let you combine multiple functions into a single function as follows:

```
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const squareOddVals = pipe(
filter((n: number) => n % 2 !== 0),
map(n => n * n)
);
```

Answer (score 5):

for short explanation, **pipe** in **RxJS**, is used to intercept the result and modify it using **RxJS** operators so that when you subscribe it you will get the final result equivalent to the logic operators you set in the **pipe** example **map**, **tap** and many more.

for angular practice guide check it here
https://angular.io/guide/rx-library

you can see the list of operators here 
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/

Comment: Thanks for reply can you give some links if you have?

Comment: I just added the links in my answer